# Port forwarding works locally over LAN IP but not over the router IP WAN from another building

Tags: ip, lan, wan

I have a commercial setup where everything is on the the same xxx.xxx.xx.1-255 network.  I have a D-link router (DIR-615) that is on this network in another building with the router IP as xxx.xxx.xx.abc and in the router the IP is also set as 10.10.0.1 in the setup admin.  (When viewing the device information the WAN is specified as the xxx.xxx.xx.abc IP and LAN is 10.10.0.1)

Behind my D-link router is a number of machines that have http pages I'd like to get access to that are on local 10.10.0.x IPs.  When I remote desktop to a machine in the other building I have web access to the router on 10.10.0.1, a machine on 10.10.0.x:80 and another on 10.10.0.y:5050 ports and am able to log in fine.

The issue.  When I try to access these ports without remote desktop from my building over the xxx.xxx.xx.abc:5050 port it doesn't work at all, but weirdly enough **when I try to access the port xxx.xxx.xx.abc:80 the log-in page opens, but does not let me log in.**

My troubleshooting:

Are your ports forwarded properly?  Yes.  Local IP 10.10... then port number specified.

Is the 5050 machine listening on 5050? Yes. Over its http port.

Is there a inbound filter?  Yes.  The range is specified for everything allowed over the xxx.xxx.xx.1-xxx.xxx.xx.255 range.

Router Firewall settings?  Disabled except for PPTP, IPSec, RTSP, SIP.

Windows Firewall settings?  Disabled.

What else can I look at?

Comment: Configuring consumer-grade networking equipment, such as the DIR-615, is specifically off-topic for this forum. See the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed.

Comment: Suggest a better forum?

Comment: You can try on Super User.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].